# Extending Recently Viewed & Recently Compared Grids

Tags: widgets, magento2.3.2, recently-viewed

I am struggling to extend the following two files in Magento 2.3.1

> \vendor\magento\module-reports\view\frontend\templates\widget\viewed\content\viewed_grid.phtml

and

> \vendor\magento\module-reports\view\frontend\templates\widget\compared\content\compared_grid.phtml

I tried extending them at:

> \ME\THEME\Magento_Reports\templates\widget\compared\content\compared_grid.phtml

and

> \ME\THEME\Magento_Reports\templates\widget\viewed\content\viewed_grid.phtml

I then ran `setup:upgrade`  and `setup:static-content:deploy -f`

But no changes took place.

To troubleshoot **I then tried editing the files in their original location**. Ran `setup:upgrade`  and `setup:static-content:deploy -f`

But still no changes?

Are these files no longer used?

To clarify it is the blocks that are inputted into the TinyMce Editor as below image.
[image]

Any Help much appreciated.

Comment: How you are checking whether the change is applied or not?

Comment: Going to the frontend and seeing if changes are reflected. I have tried intentionally breaking code etc too to try and make it thrown an error, but it does not.

Comment: Are you editing correct project folder files? can you confirm once

Comment: Yes, I have double-checked, as this was my first thought. ( I also only have one local copy running which is where I am testing it). 

As mentioned above I also tried altering the original files and no alterations were bought through to the front end.

Comment: Update: Could someone else here verify that these files are still in use, I have just completely removed them from another instance and the elements are still being rendered. I feel like I am going crazy!